# How to add results from subresources to the main resource?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Using api-platform V3.1: I have a main resource `MainResource` containing collections of two sub-resources `SubResourceOne` and `SubResourceTwo`. I'd like to provide a field "grandTotal" which holds all the amounts of the collections. Using a function `grandTotal()` does not work since the collections of the sub-resources are not ready. Using a custom serializer during serialization stage did not work either since every object is provided for itself.

What am I missing?

```
<?php

namespace App\Resource;

#[ApiResource(
    graphQlOperations: [
        new Query(
            name: 'get',
            resolver: MainResourceItemResolver::class,
            normalizationContext: [
                'groups' => [
                    MainResource::READ_ITEM
                ],
            ]
        ),
    ]
)]
class MainResource
{
    public const READ_ITEM = 'main_resource:read:item';

    #[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
    #[Groups([MainResource::READ_ITEM])]
    private string $id;

    /** @var SubResourceOne[]  */
    #[Groups([MainResource::READ_ITEM])]
    private array $subResourceOneCollection = [];

    /** @var SubResourceTwo[] */
    #[Groups([MainResource::READ_ITEM])]
    private array $subResourceTwoCollection = [];

    #[Groups([MainResource::READ_ITEM])]
    /**
     * does not work since collections are not ready
     */
    public function grandTotal(): int
    {
        $grandTotal = 0;
        foreach ($subResourceOneCollection as $subResourceOne) {
           $grandTotal += $subResourceOne->getTotalOfResourceOne(); 
        }
        foreach ($subResourceTwoCollection as $subResourceTwo) {
            $grandTotal += $subResourceTwo->getTotalOfResourceTwo(); 
        }
        return $grandTotal;
    }
}
```